# Restrict team access to areas and/or work items

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps project with a single team called "Software". Looking in Project Settings -> Team Configuration -> "Areas" tab, I can see that this team owns a single area - the "top-most" item in the project's area hierarchy, let's call this area "ProjectX". This has numerous child areas, which we use to categorise work items.

I have just created a new team called "Stakeholders", and a new area has been automatically created as part of this process, which this team now owns ("ProjectX\Stakeholders"). Am I right in saying that members of the new team will still be able to view and edit work items *anywhere* in the "ProjectX" area hierarchy? If so, what's the point of creating different teams?

What I'm trying to achieve is to allow members of the "Stakeholders" team to create new WIs and subsequently view/edit/delete those WIs. WIs created by members of the "Software" team should be completely hidden from the Stakeholders. Note also that the Software team needs to be able to edit/delete WIs created by the Stakeholders. Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in saying that members of the new team will still be able
> to view and edit work items anywhere in the "ProjectX" area hierarchy?

Yes.

> If so, what's the point of creating different teams?

Each team will use each own product, sprint backlogs, and etc. As example:  [Configure Azure Boards to support SAFe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/safe-configure-boards?view=azure-devops).

> What I'm trying to achieve is to allow members of the "Stakeholders"
> team to create new WIs and subsequently view/edit/delete those WIs.
> WIs created by members of the "Software" team should be completely
> hidden from the Stakeholders. Note also that the Software team needs
> to be able to edit/delete WIs created by the Stakeholders. Is any of
> this possible?

Yes. You can use the Area Path Security to manage access to work items under different paths: [Set permissions and access for work tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops)